# Can someone please explain this regex? ^(?=.*prodCode=).*$

Tags: java, regex

Can someone please explain this regex?

```
^(?=.*prodCode=).*$
```

Comment: There are different regExp in title and body of question. Correct it please!

Comment: Note that it is exactly the same as `^.*prodCode=.*$`, the look-ahead here is pointless.

Comment: I don't think this regex would match anything. The first ".*" would greedily match everything on the line and there would never be anything left to match "prodCode=".

Comment: Ted, the regex in the question has the first `.*` in a lookahead so the `.*` there doesn't take anything away that could make `prodCode=` match. Keppil's regex should also work because the engine will backtrack and try to make `prodCode=` match.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 9):

From [this nice regex explainer](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl):

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                      the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                    look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .                      any character except \n
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  prodCode=              'prodCode='
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                      end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .                      any character except \n
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                      before an optional \n, and the end of the string
```

**EDIT**

Since the regex in the text of the question has changed, the next-to-last line in the explanation would change to:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                     any character except \n (0 or more times (matching
                         the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: There is `^(?=.*prodCode=).*$` in the title of question

Comment: @Serjio - How about that. It would change the next-to-last line explanation to: _"any character except \n (0 or more times (matching the most amount possible))"_

Comment: Thanks!! so this would match a line starts with prodCode=XXXX and does not match #prodCode=xxxx or someProdCode=xxxx right.

Comment: @rtv - There's a '.' before "prodCode=" in the regex, so there has to be (exactly) one character before "prodCode=". It would not match a line starting with "prodCode=" but it would match a line starting with "#prodCode=".

Comment: @TedHopp - I was thinking that .* is Zero or more chars, is it wrong?

Comment: @rtv - Oops. I missed the "*" added to the first ".". You're right.

Answer (score 1):

From the beggining of line searhinng position any symbols before `prodCode=`. `(?=)` means just check of position not match. So in your situation if in the line exists string like `any symbol + prodCode=` then we match whole line if not then return false.

Answer (score 1):

This matches if the string has `prodCode=` anywhere in it and matches the complete string.

Another way of writing it (roughly, abusing a method return value as the regex matcch) would be

```
if (s.indexOf("prodCode=") != -1)
    return s;
```

Comment: so the pattern applied to `"XprodCode=9"` would return `"X"`?

Comment: No. I was basing my old answer on the mangled and ill-formatted regex in the original question. I have since revised it